# Is the Apple power adapter exchange program still available?

Tags: iphone, charger

My USB power adapter (model A1300) that came with my Iphone 4 died on duty today.
Just by coincidence [I saw this site](https://www.apple.com/il/support/usbadapter-european/) right now, that claim Apple will replace all of the A1300 models with the A1400 once *free of charge*.
I wanted to ask if this procedure is still available in Europe, so I can use it.

Comment: Didn't you see where it said... "The Exchange Process" ... "Bring the affected adapter(s) to an Apple Retail Store or a participating Apple Authorized Service Provider. We will need to verify your iPhone serial number as part of the exchange process so please bring your iPhone with you."?

Comment: @user3439894 I saw it, but didn't know if it's still genuine.

Comment: The fact that the page is still available and without an ending date it's logical to assume it's still valid.  Select your Country from the list box and see what it has to say and follow through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - if you have an adapter that might be covered, it would be replaced. Check with AppleCare or visit an Apple Store for service - whatever is your preference. The page has good information on finding service as well as having your iPhone serial number to validate the exchange.

Update June 2016: The "exchange" is r ported to now be handled using a repair procedure.